# Commas after a dependent clause

Tags: commas

I am currently learning about commas again. I would like to know if this is correct.

For a while, the situation seems to improve, but shortly after that, Mary decides to finally kill herself.

I chose to do it that way because "For a while" is an adverbial determination, ",but" introduces an independent clause, and "shortly after that" is introducing the independent clause?

I still have the feeling there is something wrong with the 3rd comma....?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"For a while, the situation seems to improve, but shortly after that, Mary decides to finally kill herself."

This is grammatically correct.

Think of it this way: "but" as a conjunction, particularly in this case, introduces an independent clause; likewise, what comes before "but" is also able to stand on its own.

If you want to, you may do this:

> "For a while, the situation seems to improve, **but,** shortly after that, Mary decides to finally kill herself."

This is also correct. In the second example, I just set aside the detail "shortly after that" because, even though it makes the sentence more specific, it is technically not critical.